# Django extends/include - bug?

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm trying to use both extends and include tags in one template, just like:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
 <div id="content">
  <nav class="mainMenu">
   {% include "list.html" %}
  </nav>
 </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Unfortunately what is displayed is only list.html without contents from layout.html and file that is including the list.html. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most probably only rendering list.html in your view, check for that.